# Batch file to install software silently (or without user interaction)

Tags: batch-file, installation

I am trying to make batch file for installing software silently. Is there a way to make it automatically select `Next` and `Finish` during the installing process?

Comment: I don't know if you can do this in a batch file, is it your own software you're trying to install? If so you could configure the code to accept a commandline argument that would tell it to "select next" or not give the next option.

Comment: From the command line, try typing `Setup /?` (replacing Setup with the actual installer name.)  It may offer command line options you can use in your script.

Answer (score 0):

We need more details to answere your question. what is exactly sw?? is it shockwave player, in this case follow these instructions http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/195/tn_19572.html by adding the /s argument.

Comment: I was confused too, but "sw" is "software".

Answer (score 0):

Usually with most programs you can add the command /silent or /verysilent when installing them through the command line.  I know this works with UltraVNC.  If it is your own program then you would have to add that option using [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/) or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If the application does not support silent installation, you will need to look at something like [AuotIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/). You can use it to automate pressing buttons and entering keystrokes.